# Can I use a Runestone of Power to cast a spell I normally can't?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, magic-items

I have a player who wants to use a [page of spell knowledge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/m-p/page-of-spell-knowledge/) in combination with a [Runestone of power](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/r-z/runestone-of-power/) to cast a 5th level spell as a level 9 sorcerer.

Is it possible to do this by RAW?  If not, what would be some potential balance implications if it were allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, and no.

You can certainly use a Runestone to cast a spell that you have gained via a Page of Spell Knowledge.

Page of Spell Knowledge says

> If the bearer is a spontaneous spellcaster and has that spell on her class spell list, she may use her spell slots to cast that spell as if it were one of her spells known.

and Runestone of Power says

> Once per day, a spontaneous caster can draw upon a runestone of power to cast a spell [...] and expends that runestone’s power for the day rather than one of the spellcaster’s actual spell slots for the day.

So we can treat the spell on the page as being on the users list of spells know, and can cast it with one of our spell slots.

We can then use a Runestone to expend its power instead of using one of our spell slots, allowing us to cast the spell via the runestone.

---

We *cannot*, however, use a Runestone to cast a spell of a higher level than we have slots for. From the items description, it allows the use of the Runestones power *instead of* one of the spellcasters spell slots. Since level 9 sorcerers only have up to level 4 spell slots, then there is nothing for the Runestone to be used in place of.

The Use Magic Device skill can allow a character to bypass these limitations by making a roll to "fake" having met certain requirements. First, you would need to emulate the required minimum ability score if you don't meet that already, which has a base DC of the minimum ability score value +10, so in your example of a level 5 spell, DC 25 assuming you had a 14 or less. Then, you would also need to emulate having a particular class feature, which has a DC of the level of the class you need to be for that feature + 20, so in this case, sorcerers get level 5 slots at level 10 for DC30. So in order for any character to be able to use these items, you would need to have a Charisma of 15 (which I assume the sorcerer already has) and also pass a UMD check of DC30 in order to activate Runestone any time you wish to activate it. You would also need to pass this same DC for the Page, and have to re-check every hour(in game) to keep it active, as it is a passive effect item. And remember, UMD is Trained Only, so if you don't have any ranks in it, you cannot even make the attempt.

---

As a side note, this would be significantly more expensive and difficult than purchasing a couple of scrolls of the same spell you wanted to cast, as scrolls are significantly cheaper and easier to use. If your caster level matches the scrolls, your type of spell casting matches its (arcane/divine), it's on your spell list, and you have the requisite minimum ability score, you don't have to make a check.

Since all arcane scrolls are assumed to be made by wizards by default, a level 5 arcane spell scroll would be caster level 9, and because sorcerers and wizards share their spell list, any wizard made scroll will be on your list, meaning you could cast off of the scroll automatically even if you don't have level 5 spell slots.

And should you meet all other requirements besides the caster level, they can still cast it by making a aster level check with a DC of 1 + the scrolls caster level (in this case, DC10), which in this case, would mean a DC 10 caster level check, meaning you pass on a 1 or better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116191/discussion-between-ben-barden-and-revenantbacon).